# Change Display order of Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

When a new column is added to a current table, this appears in the last column. eg:
added AGE columns to Students table
SELECT * FROM Students; "would show the AGE column right at the end.

Question: is it possible to change the order of these columns when such commands are executed?

Comment: Please, read this: [PostgreSQL - Is it possible to alter the column order (position) in a table?](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/09/postgresql-is-it-possible-to-alter-column-order-position-in-a-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing table, you could create a VIEW with the columns reorganized, then of course, you could also type out the columns. You could also create a new table.

Comment: for which db it will work. as far as I know it is available only in MySQL not in any other DB

Comment: @Fahmi apologies, didn't notice the tag (was looking at the wrong filter, my mistake, removed that part)

Comment: yes I also knew that you didn't look at the tag, however, you can suggest in your answer to create  a new table

Comment: that kinda was already there 'or recreate the table as a whole', but I rephrased it

Comment: will reorganizing the column name on a table level edit ensure the change would be permanent?

Comment: yeah, table columns don't shift randomly